# Scrolling to CollectionView Cell that is off screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard

I'm designing a UI with a horizontal collection view (see below) [image]I can scroll left or right to see the cells but when I let go, it bounces back to the center. The behavior I want is that when you scroll to cells off screen, it stops on them (not bounces back).  Unchecking Bouncing on Scroll in the attributes inspector has no impact, unchecking Bounce Horizontally doesn't let me scroll at all.  How can I achieve the desired behavior?

[image]

Comment: You should constrain the collection view to the leading and trailing margins; it should not be outside the bounds of the containing view. A collectionview is built around a scroll view so it can manage the viewport onto a larger view area itself.

Comment: @Paulw11 so I can't do what I'm trying to do with a collectionView then as far as scrolling to items that are off screen?

Comment: I don't understand; a horizontal collectionview seems to do  exactly what you want, but you ave to ensure that the view itself is constrained to the visible area. The scroll view in the collectionview handles the offscreen cells for you